# fillText no longer working? (FireFox 27.0.1)

Tags: firefox

This is a piece of HTML that demonstrates the problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>canvas fillText()</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.font = "40px sans serif ";
      context.lineWidth = 3;
      context.strokeStyle = "blue";
      context.strokeText("Hello World!", 40, 40);
      context.fillStyle = "black";
      context.fillText("Hello World!", 40, 80);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

While other browsers show both the outlined and solid text, FF27 does not render the text using fillText().
Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment due to reputation limitations, but I am running into the same issue :(.  Unable to draw filled text in Firefox 27.0.1 on Windows 7 Pro SP1.  I tried changing the fillStyle property to '#000', '#000000', 'black', 'rgb(0,0,0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,.8)'.  I also attempted to use the deprecated functions 'mozDrawText' and 'mozPathText', both of which have been removed from the API.  Please answer your post if you figure out a workaround.  For now, I guess I will just call both strokeText and fillText with black, and hope nobody notices the hollow text in Firefox.

Just so you know, I reported this as a bug at:
    https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=982837

Comment: I just updated to the latest version of Firefox (v28.0), and this bug has been resolved.

Comment: I have to disagree.  Nothing changed for me with V28.
System is Win7/64.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved in FireFox 30.0, AFAICT.

Comment: Could you find a link to substantiate that fact and add it to your comment?

Comment: That -is- a link that substantiates the claim, so you should have started with "yes"